# What does pointer reversal in mark and sweep garbage collection buy you?

Tags: pointers, compiler-construction, garbage-collection

I feel like I am missing something painfully simple but I am trying to understand mark and sweep garbage collection per Andrew Appel's Modern Compiler Implementation in ML book and there's a small paragraph inside the Mark and Sweep section titled Pointer Reversal (270).

At this point I think I understand how it works. In a nutshell, as you traverse the graph you flip all the pointers so that your predecessor is inside your set of fields. Then when you are done with a given element, you flip the pointers back so they point at the right place again.

If that is correct, what exactly does it buy you? Appel attempts to explain this but I don't fully grok his wording.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

During marking, objects fall into three categories:

1. Objects that have not been marked
2. Objects that have been marked, but can point to unmarked objects
3. Objects that have been marked and point to marked objects only

As marking proceeds, objects change state from category 1 to category 2, and from category 2 to category 3.
The garbage collector has to keep track of all objects in category 2 so that it can find all unmarked objects.  But where does it store that information?  Garbage collection may be running when memory is completely full, so it cannot dynamically allocate a data structure.  It should build a data structure holding objects in category 2, *using the memory that is already allocated*.  Pointer reversal is an algorithm for building a linked list of these objects without allocating memory.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean now. So it's a way to get stack-like functionality when you don't have enough memory available to actually allocate a stack. That's actually pretty clever (as these things always are).

Small issue but you mean during the marking stage right? Sweeping is what comes after?

Comment: It's interesting to note that some garbage-collection schemes use handles (indirect pointers), but .net uses direct pointers; when an object is relocated, every reference to that object has to be updated to point to the new address.  I would conjecture that's why objects are required to be large enough to hold three object references even though there are only two object references' worth of overhead: when an object gets relocated, the first 12/24 bytes of memory that was formerly used by the old object can be used as scratchpad for the GC process.  Does that sound right?